# Argument not being passed to screen

Tags: flutter, dart

In main.dart created such routes:

```js
routes: {
          '/home': (context) => HomeScreenWidget(),
          '/color_picker': (context) => ColorPickerWidget(),
          TextValueScreen.routeName: (context) =>
          const TextValueScreen(color: '',),
        },
        initialRoute: '/home',
```

I'm trying to pass an argument "color" to the following screen:

```js
// default value of select
  String selectedValue = "Yellow";

  // next step route
  void _changeColor(String color) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      TextValueScreen.routeName,
      arguments: {color: color}
    );
  }
```

```js
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => _changeColor(selectedValue),
                child: const Text('Next'),
            ),
```

But the argument is not passed. How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to access arguments on a target route:

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate and pass the Color argument like this

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      TextValueScreen.routeName,
      arguments: Colors.yellow
      //you can pass any color you want
    );
```

Access the Navigation inside your TextValueScreen

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   var colorArg = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Color;
   return yourWidget();
}
```

For this to work the argument needs to be a Color obejct. If you want to pass another kind of object just specify what you are giving as a navigation parameter inside your build method

Comment: If more code was pasted, It would much more clear and faster to understand the answer.

Comment: I hope I made it easier now :)

Comment: A good pattern to follow is creating 'global' controllers and accessing them inside any file with the following lib. I suggest you take a look, it is very easy and productive https://pub.dev/packages/get_it